# Function of an array

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have an array defined in this way (extracting the third column of a dataset):

```
value=[]
value.append((p[3]))
x=np.array(value)
```

How can I do if I would like to obtain a new array containing the Log10 (o a different function) of the array x? 
I have tried with:

```
logx=np.array(log(x))
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ufunc' object is not subscriptable.
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is p[3]?  Could you please give a complete and working (but very short) example which displays this behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use: `logx = np.log(x)`

Comment: I've trid but it gives me this error:
    NotImplementedError: Not implemented for this type
what does it mean?

Comment: @user2044983: probably that your `x` isn't composed of numbers but of strings.  What does `print set(map(type, x))` return?

Comment: Please clarify what values has `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Nikolay's answer isn't working for you, but you could also do:

`logx = map(np.log, x)`